# Prove $|f^{\prime}(a)|< \frac{Im f(a)}{Im a} $ for analytic self mapping on upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

$f:H \to H$ is a analytic mapping, where $H$ is the upper half plane, then $a \in H$, prove the inequality : $|f^{\prime}(a)|< \frac{Im f(a)}{Im a} $. I tried to use Schwarz Lemma to solve it, but I could not get the $Im f(a)$ part, I have no other ideas. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Try to use a Schwarz-Pick theorem :https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma.

Comment: @SeewooLee, thanks, got it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma). I assume you know about [Cayley's map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform).